# Getting Image Size Problem

Tags: jquery, resize

I've been trying to get image-loading dynamically- size dynamically to set wrapper div height and width via jQuery.

But the problem is `alert($(".imageContainer").height()` shows `0` since I believe the images has not been loaded when I call this function.

The process is : when user click a thumbnail on a grid, a modal window pops up and and some simple jQuery code set the `src` attribute on this modal window to show corresponding image.

Lets say :

```
$(".thumb-img").click(function(){
    $(".bigImage").attr("src","somewhere/"+$(this).attr("data-imageid")+".jpg");
    //needs to know whether image has been loaded or not
    $(".imageContainer").height($(".bigImage").height());
    $(".imageContainer").width($(".bigImage").width());
});
```

The images size are not consistent and I need to set size according to their size dynamically.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing some quotes where you're retrieving the width and heigth

Comment: @Rob, yeah in actual code they are complete. I forgot when I wrote down here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> needs to know whether image has been
>   loaded or not

If you want to know whether or not image has loaded, you can use the `load` event (it works for images too):

```
$(".bigImage").load(function(){
  alert(' I am loaded...');
});
```

When you put your image-related code in `load` of the window through, all images and other resources are loaded by then, so you can safely assume all images are loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // by now all images are loaded
});
```

Comment: Images are loaded dynamically and not all images are loaded at the same time. When user clicks on a thumbnail, before that bigger images is not loaded but after it is loaded and it applies to all other big images. Your solution will work for just one image and that's all.